# Zabbix 6.0 Предобработка JavaScript

Tags: javascript, zabbix

Сделал Шаблон для мониторинга RAID контроллера Adaptec.
У шаблона создал элемент данных (info), который собирает информацию. Его полученные данные (сокращенно):

```
Controllers found: 1
Controller information
   Controller Status                        : Optimal
   Channel description                      : SAS/SATA
```

Создал зависимы элемент данных от элемента info, который на первом проходе предобработки (регулярное выражение) ищет значение "Controller Status":

```
Controller Status +: (.*)
```

А на втором проходе (JavaScript) присваивает значение:

```
if (value == "Optimal") {
    value = 1;
}
else { value = 0;
}
return value;
```

Но на выходе я всегда получаю 0, а не 1. Хотя тест проходов возвращает 1, но в реале у элемента данных присваивается значение 0. Первый проход возвращает Optimal (проверил отдельно, удалял второй проход), но второй почему-то всегда 0. Где я ошибся? Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Скорее всего значение value при втором проходе не перезаписывается и на вход подается не Optimal. Поставьте перед вызовом console.log(value)

Comment: Моя ошибка оказалась глупой, каюсь. Приходящую с сервера информацию (последние данные) я выделял мышкой в браузере и копировал в тест предобработки. Но при захвате текста, обрезался пробел после Optimal. На самом деле приходило не "Optimal", а "Optimal ". Поставил value.trim() и пробел обрезался, и все проходы отработались как надо. Вопрос закрыт

Answer (score 0):

Моя ошибка оказалась глупой, каюсь. Приходящую с сервера информацию (последние данные) я выделял мышкой в браузере и копировал в тест предобработки. Но при захвате текста, обрезался пробел после **Optimal**.

На самом деле приходило не **"Optimal"**, а **"Optimal "**. Поставил **value.trim()** и пробел обрезался, и все проходы отработались как надо. Вопрос закрыт.